# Awstats IIS Log configuration fields extended

Tags: logging, awstats

Good Day:

We are *implementing* AwStat in our IIS Servers and after reading the documentation and browsing some googled results, we still have questions... so where's the best site for asking them? hehe :)

- *IIS Log configuration*. Awstat is very specific in what you must "check" and what not to check, **but it gives no reason for that**... will it work correctly with more fields?
- If we configure both *sc-bytes* and *cs-bytes*... Will it duplicate the info? I think both fields are useful.
- The same server redirect by Tomcat Conector to three different contents (/blabla /blablo2 /bleble)... ¿What will you do to get different statics of them? Awtstats can't filter by 'cs-uri-stem' filter...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this URL can be usefull http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154982/what-is-the-best-log-analysis-tool-that-you-used if anyone gest here while searching for log utilities

Answer (score 1):

It's not duplicate information since cs-bytes and sc-bytes are different.

- **SC-Bytes** = Server to Client Bytes (Outbound Sent Information)
- **CS-Bytes** = Client to Server Bytes (Inbound Received Information)

Comment: Thanks. I was worried about that. The problem is that *we considerer both useful*, but seems awstats only use one.

Comment: Go with received as this will stat people surfing the website while the outbound is for data sent which isn't very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Awstats is very flexible about how it parses your log files.  It uses a configuration parameter called `LogFormat` to know the format your log files.  If you log additional fields, you would have to modify your `LogFormat` configuration to let awstats know what the extra fields mean.

The official documentation for `LogFormat` is here: http://awstats.sourceforge.net/docs/awstats_faq.html#PERSONALIZEDLOG  Here is an article about it that is formatted better and easier to understand than the official documentation: http://www.internetofficer.com/awstats/log-format/

Comment: I checked both yesterday, and again today with more "deep" but seems that Awtstat has no way to use cs-bytes. All examples and parameters refer to sc-bytes. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you implement Awstats into IIS? It is better to install it by means of Plesk and them use the statistics program via Plesk panel.

Comment: Well, the web is mainly in the intranet, we thought that get some stadistics will be "nice" but we dont really need a very big system like plesk... We have some apache too, and awtats can be configured to both...